# Use ObjectId.GenerateNewId() or leave MongoDB to create one?

Tags: c#, mongodb

In C# I can use the ObjectId.GenerateNewId() to generate ObjectId values.

Most of the time when I insert a document in a collection I do not set the value of _id fields. MongoDB creates the ObjectId values automatically.

I would like to ask if it is safe to set it manually by using the ObjectId.GenerateNewId() method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you insert a new mongodb document the son driver check if exist a property with the `BsonId` AttributeClass. If exist and is null it create a new ObjectId, if doesn't exist during the document insertion mongodb will generate e new `ObjectId`.
Sometimes users encounter problem with "only zero" ObjectId, for this reason my suggestion is to use a combination of `BsonID` attribute class and `ObjectId.GenerateNewId` so you are sure that that property will not have weird behaviour.
e.g.

```
public class SomeClass {

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId MySuperId { get; set; }

    public SomeClass() {
        this.MySuperId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }

}
```

Comment: Using your code exactly:
"Error converting value {null} to type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'. Path 'Id',

Comment: Using this payload.
{
  "Id": null
}

Comment: This only seems to work if I set the id to nullable like: 

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        #nullable enable
        public ObjectId? Id { get; set; } = null;
        #nullable disable

This is a way it can be null.